# Openbabel: Generate random 3D geometry

Tags: computational-chemistry, software, cheminformatics

Is it possible with openbabel to generate random 3D geometries (i.e. conformers) of a molecule without taking energy into account? Ideally with the property of being truly random, so that after generating conformers like this for a sufficient amount of time, a good coverage of the conformational space is obtained. Because the --conformer options of openbabel takes energy into account, but I want to input the geometries into a qc program that then calculates the energies for the conformers.

Comment: I would generate a normal coordination file and write a little script that twists desired bond-angles by different amounts

Comment: If you create actual random 3D geometries I expect 99.9% of those being absolute garbage and they won't have anything to do with different confomers. There are techniques which allow for confomer search, for example simulated annealing.

Comment: ^ this. I don't know what exactly you want to achieve, but maybe some kind of MD simulation could help you get enough snapshots? I mean you have something in the scale of $n_{steps} \cdot N_{atoms}^3$ calculations to do if you want a random, statistical approach to all angles. I don't know, but my boss would ask me if I was crazy if I would start 10k calculations of which 9990 would be garbage...

Comment: Well, the thing with the openbabel conformer generator is that it is often not expolaritive enough (sometimes even only a single conformer is returned). So my idea was to generate random conformers and optimize them afterwards to have a more robust method.

Comment: 99.9% no problem: then I just generate 10000 structures and get 10 conformers that are actually different. because openbabel just gives me basically always the same conformer.

Comment: And how are you gonna go through 10000 coords to find the relevant ones?

I would start the other way around. Think about which conformers are important, generate only those coordinates. 

If you would tell us what you are aiming towards maybe we could help better...

Comment: 10000 coordinates with MM is pretty bearable, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

**Random conformer search generates random conformers**

Open Babel, like many conformer sampling tools, has a set of common dihedral angles to sample. This minimizes the search space, e.g., only 3-4 likely cases for each rotatable bond.

The RandomConformerSearch method indeed generates conformers using a random sampling of dihedral angles. It then (optionally) runs a force field for some number of steps to minimize any steric clashes. No energies are considered.

If you're finding only one conformer output, that's because you're not using the `--writeconformers` flag:
http://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3DStructureGen/multipleconformers.html

Comment: PS - I only recently saw this question. There is an Open Babel support forum - I'm not coming to Chem.SE as often as I'd like.

Comment: OK, I will keep the open babel support forum in mind. But I tried several combinations of input flags and always got a single conformer. If I have time on my hands, I will try to make a minimal example of the problem I ran into and post it into the open babel forum. By the way, Avogadro and OpenBabel are great, keep up the nice work : ) Anything else in planning?

Comment: Doesn't matter what combination of input flags - if you don't use `--writeconformers` you'll only get the lowest energy one. Alternatively, write a Python script. :-)